# Declaring service UI in DCOS results in broken links

Tags: dcos

I need a mini-hdfs service that can run in a single agent, so I started building one in a docker container.  I then deployed it to DCOS.  The Namenode UI comes up, but un-styled. It turns out that the references inside the UI we not prefixed.

My service is at `http://m1.dcos/service/small-hdfs/dfshealth.html`

The browser generates requests such as `http://m1.dcos/static/bootstrap-3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Instead of `http://m1.dcos/service/small-hdfs/static/bootstrap-3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css`

This is my marathon.json - very basic for now - I'll expose the volumes after I get it basically working ...

How do I fix this.  If I can pass the prefix into the container, I may be able to configure a Hadoop property with the prefix, but not sure if that is possible.  I also did not see any documented way of passing this prefix.

```
{
  "id": "small-hdfs",
  "cmd": "/root/docker_entrypoint.sh",
  "cpus": 1.5,
  "mem": 4096.0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "slowenthal/small-hdfs",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "containerPort": 9000, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp" },
        { "containerPort": 50070, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp" }
      ]
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "DCOS_SERVICE_NAME": "small-hdfs",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_PORT_INDEX": "1",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_SCHEME": "http"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see a bit more detailed info here:  But it implies that the adminrouter should handle it

https://github.com/dcos/adminrouter

Comment: It may be related to this bug ... 

https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-389

Certainly the techniques for working around this need documentation.  Obviously there is an existing HDFS service, and the admin UI works correctly.